# No ID error with Update in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is piece of code:

```
  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.update_attributes(params[:category], :as => :roles_update)  
      @category = Category.find[params[:id]]
      render 'show', :notice => 'Category was successfully updated'
    else
      @categories = Category.all
      render 'index'
    end 
  end
```

And errors when executing the above:

```
  Couldn't find Category without an ID
```

However there is category id (=1) in the parameter dump:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"aFk+bcHKA3zwck1PgrNOwVvZfeXtsT57ywHGiB4odDY=",
 "category"=>{"description"=>"audio/video",
 "active"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Update Category",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

The code would be no error if comment out  #@category = Category.find[params[:id]] in IF loop. But rspect gives error:  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:

Any suggestion about the problem? Thanks

Comment: Could be this line: `@category = Category.find[params[:id]]`. Should be using round brackets: `@category = Category.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: The square brackets will definitely be an issue. You can also probably simplify your code by writing `@category.reload` rather than `@category = Category.find(params[:id])` (line 5)

Comment: Got a nil.reload error saying "The error occurred while evaluating nil.reload".  Here is the edit method: def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @category = Category.find[params[:id]]
```

should be:

```
 @category = Category.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Yes, it should be (). However the rspec still stuck with " ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Category without an ID" with first @category = Category.find(params[:id]) right after def update. thanks.